# How can I concatenate images in one matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have 64 images (Their names are like that: 00001.jpg, ... , 00064.jpg). I want to create a matrix with these images which would give the result below:

```
[img1 img2 ... img8
 img9 img10 ...img16
 ...
 img57 ........img64]
```

I've tried horzcat(), imtile(), montage() methods, but these gave me the results I didn't want.
I expect a 8x8 matrix with images. I want to do above programmatically using Matlab but couldn't find any solution.
How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Are all the 64 images the same length? Also will those always be a constant number?

Comment: What are the sizes of your images? What do you mean you want to create a 8x8 matrix with images? Putting all images in a 8x8 cell such that you can retrieve them with indexing e.g. `imageCollection{1}`? Consider provide a more detailed [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `imtile` seems to do exactly that. What's the specific problem you have encountered? Please post the relevant code to get more help. Also, what do you mean by an 8x8 matrix? You will get an (8*N)x(8*N)-sized image, where NxN is the original image size

Answer (score 0):

An image is basically a matrix.

This is how you concatenate 2 matrices ([link](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html))

```
A = ones(1,4);
B = zeros(1,4);
C = [A B];  //Horizontal
D = [A; B]; //Vertical
```

Use this logic to join your matrices horizontally and vertically.

Said that, You should be aware of matrix size and its mis-match problems.

Answer (score 0):

The function imtile is what you want. It's your expectation of an 8x8 size that is incorrect. Take the following example.

```
A = magic(2);

>> imtile({A,A,A,A})

ans =

 1     3     1     3
 4     2     4     2
 1     3     1     3
 4     2     4     2
```

Since imtile accepts an ImageDatastore, the easiest thing to do would be:

```
imds = imageDatastore(pathToYourImages)
tiledImage = imtile(imds);
```